# Object Mapper that includes Member Fields

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper

Is there any Object-Object mapper that will support mapping to and from public member variables in addition to properties?

I would like to use a mapping solution, and unfortunately I do not control the code for one side of the object graph.

```
    public class Source
    {
        public string A_String { get; set; }
        public int A_Number { get; set; }
    }
    public class ICantControlThisClass
    {
        public string A_String;
        public int A_Number;
    }
```

Can AutoMapper or ValueInjecter or any other OO Mapper accomplish this:

```
    var source = new Source() { A_String = "hi", A_Number = 10 };
    var target = new ICantControlThisClass();
    Mapper.Map(source, target);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. Just create map

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, ICantControlThisClass>();
```

And Automapper will do the rest:

```
var source = new Source() { A_String = "hi", A_Number = 10 };
var target = Mapper.Map<ICantControlThisClass>(source);
```